# Spring Security LDAP IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException

Tags: spring-security

I have racked my brain about this for a while now, and have gotten nowhere.  This is what is in my security-context.xml.  This is going to be a servlet.

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.html" default-target-url="" />
    <security:anonymous />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch">
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean id="authoritiesPopulator"
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:constructor-arg value="" />
            <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
            <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
            <beans:property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg
        value="thepathtomyLDAPdatabase" />
    <beans:property name="userDn"
        value="theuserpathforLDAP" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="mypassword" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userSearch"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="CN=Users" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1"
        value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
    <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have spring-tx on your classpath. If you are using a build tool, you can figure out its configuration by looking at something like [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-tx%7C3.2.0.RELEASE%7Cjar) to explain what the configuration would look like. For example, if you are using Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE and Maven you will want to ensure you have the following in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that it is critical to ensure that your Spring dependency versions match (i.e. the artifacts with group org.springframework should match), so if you are not using Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE elsewhere, you will want to ensure that you change the version number to match your other Spring dependencies.